# In the SSIS Script Component, what is the difference between ProcessInput() and Input0_ProcessInputRow()

Tags: c#, ssis, script-component

I have always assumed that the Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row) method runs once for every row being passed through the script component:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //Code in here runs once for each row coming in to the Script Component
}
```

I have recently discovered another method called [ProcessInput(int inputID,
    PipelineBuffer buffer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt212872.aspx#M:Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.ProcessInput(System.Int32,Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer)) and am wondering if I am doing something wrong by never using it.

What are the scenarios where I would use Input0_ProcessInputRow() vs ProcessInput()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, it turns out that using the _ProcessInputRow() method is the correct way to process inputs in an SSIS Script Component.

What I discovered in my research is that _ProcessInput() can be used to manually iterate over the Buffer and send results to _ProcessInputRow() (however it is not necessary to do so unless yo uhave a reason to):

```
public override void  Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
{
    while (Buffer.NextRow())
    {
        Input0_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
    }
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //Process one row's worth of data by calling "Row."
}
```

Additionally, I found that the ProcessInput method is use even further upstream from _ProcessInput and _ProcessinputRow().  ProcessInput() is the method that allows you to manipulate the raw buffer data coming in as an input:

```
public override void ProcessInput(int InputID, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer buffer)
{
    IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.GetObjectByID(InputID);

    while (buffer.NextRow())
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < input.InputColumnCollection.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            IDTSInputColumn100 inputColumn = input.InputColumnCollection[columnIndex];
            var test = buffer[columnIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it would ever be necessary to use ProcessInput(), but it's nice to know it is available. To answer my question, _ProcessInputRow() is the correct method to use in order to process data coming in through an input.